Converting a URL from UBB/phpBB markup back to HTML using preg_replace()
How do you convert these types of UBB code back into HTML?  My function for bold, italic and underline is:
function convertFromUBB($articleBody){
   $articleBody = preg_replace( "#\[b\](.+?)\[/b\]#is", "<b>\\1</b>", $articleBody );
   $articleBody = preg_replace( "#\[u\](.+?)\[/u\]#is", "<u>\\1</u>", $articleBody ); 
   $articleBody = preg_replace( "#\[i\](.+?)\[/i\]#is", "<i>\\1</i>", $articleBody );     
    return $articleBody;
}

Example UBB code for URL replacement comes in two formats:
[url]www (dot) domain (dot) com[/url] which would translate to <a href=" http: //www(dot) domain (dot)com">domain(dot) com</a>

and

[url=" http: //www(dot) domain(dot) com"]www. domain .com[/url] which would also translate to <a href=" http: //www. domain. com">www .domain. com</a>

Apologies, I am not sure how to write example URLs.
Converting [URL] UBB markup back to HTML I am finding difficult to write the appropriate preg_replace() and cannot find a google result.   thanks ahead of time

The regexp would be: \[url="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[/url\].

I am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "." in /    .. it doesnt like that first period... my code is:      $articleBody = preg_replace( "[url="(.?)"](.?)[/url]", "<a href=>\1", $articleBody );

not sure how to escape those double quotes...

if I escape both double quotes after [url I get this error:   Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric, backslash, or NUL in

Sounds like you forgot the # delimiters, like you have in the other regexes.

BTW, it's usually better to use single quotes around the regex, so you don't have to worry about $ and escape sequences.

How to write the preg_replace() to convert to HTML if you have UBB code like this?  [url="https://video-ocean.com/"]Video Ocean[/url]     .. thanks

Use two regular expressions, one for [url]www.XXX[/url] and another for [url="XXX"]YYY[/url]. The first one can add the http:// prefix when it creates the URL in the <a> tag. The second simply uses XXX as given.
$articleBody = preg_replace('#\[url\](www\.(.*?))\[/url\]#is', '<a href="http://$1">$2</a>', $articleBody);
$articleBody = preg_replace('#\[url="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[/url\]#is', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $articleBody);

DEMO
BTW, the documentation says that $1 is preferred over \1 to refer to capture groups.

Thanks for the response but that does not do anything.  The UBB code remains unchanged despite implementing the above answer.  Sample data after using the above preg_replace you suggested outputs UBB code still:  [url="https:// video-ocean . com/"]Video Ocean[/url] is a stoc...

I just tested it, and I got <a href="https:// video-ocean . com/">Video Ocean</a> is a stoc

I added a link to an online demo showing it works.
